# jquery how do I get css properties for a div

Tags: jquery, css, styles

Here's the problem, I need to get css properties for a div. The css is located in `<style></<style>`.

What happens is that some of the css properties are returned, while not some.

Below is the code, this is an example which I have modified.

If you run the example; you see that border-width, border-color and border-style do not return a value.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { height: 50px; margin: 5px; padding: 5px; float: left}
#box1 { width: 50px; color: yellow; background-color: blue;  border-width:2px; border-color:#0C6; border-style:solid}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
<div id="box1">1</div>
<script>
$("div").click(function () {
var html = ["The clicked div has the following styles:"];
var styleProps = $(this).css( ["border-width","border-color","border-style","width", "height", "color", "background-color"] );
$.each( styleProps, function( prop, value ) {
html.push( prop + ": " + value );
});
$( "#result" ).html( html.join( "<br>" ) );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.  I should mention that this code works with Chrome.  I tested with FF18 and the first three css values are not returned.

Comment: Returns the values just fine for me in Chrome ?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aBSch/

Comment: oh, [this is working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/DZBJn/)

Comment: Just looked at you fiddle, I am am running latest FF and I don't see a value for border-style, border-width and border-color.

Comment: I just tested with Chrome and it works fine,  Is there a problem with FF not supporting these css values?

Answer (score 0):

#### Just use `.css()`!

```
$(element).css();
```

#### Or using HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Computed Style Example</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.special {
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getBackgroundColor() {
                var oDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
                alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oDiv, null).backgroundColor);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" class="special"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Get Background Color" onclick="getBackgroundColor()" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem with my code.  Apparently in FF 18, you must specify the full css value, not the shortcut.

Here is my solution, I specify the full css property as below.

```
border-bottom-color:green;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:2px;
```

Then my jquery to retrieve the values is as follows:

var styleProps = $(this).css( ["border-bottom-width","border-bottom-color","border-bottom-style","width", "height", "color", "background-color"] );

This should hold true for all css properties that have a shortcut.

Thanks to all the people that helped with this question.

Thanks

Chris